# Windows 7 Professional - How can I switch wifi routers by using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wifi, router

I have two wifi routers, one for home and the other for work(vpn), and I need to switch them every day.  If I just turn off the connection to one and connect to the other, there seems to be some kind of IP address conflict killing the connection.  I fix it by issuing three commands:

1. ipconfig /release
2. ipconfig /flushdns
3. ipconfig /renew

This is a tedious process, so I'd like to write a batch file that switches between the routers, and issues these commands.  My question is, can I switch wifi routers by <strike>command prompt</strike> batch file?

Comment: Did you already try simply putting these 3 commands into .bat file? Btw. your last sentence makes no sense since you stated that you currently use the command prompt.

Comment: Ask yourself this - what is a batch file?  Answer... It's a text file containing a series of commands to be executed by the command line interpreter.  Excuse me, but I made the assumption the terms would be synonymous here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny how you guys delete accepted answers, when it was actually helpful.

In any case, I was pointed to this site, and it gave what I needed:
http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-manage-a-wireless-wifi-network-from-the-command-line-in-windows-7/

netsh wlan connect name=networkname